# NSURL value goes null when url string parameter has space..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsurl

I am parsing xml through my aspx page to my iphone app. I am doing this way to get XML data from url and append into NSData like this below.

```
NSString *urlString =
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abc.com/parsexml.aspx?query=%@",
                            searchBar.text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

error comes when my urlString has whitespace between characters e.g(http://www.abc.com/parsexml.aspx?query=iphone 32gb 3gs)

please help me. What should i do to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 18):

Use `NSString`'s `-(NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;` to encode the url request data.

Check the doc [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

```
NSString *urlString =
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abc.com/parsexml.aspx?query=%@",
[searchBar.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use %20 Instead of Space Remove Space By %20 in your URL String

Hope It Will Help You..